# Is there a way to use the "primary toolbar" with QT or Java?

Tags: java, python, application-development, qt

I am developping a software in order to compete in the Ubuntu App Contest, but I am having a problem.

I started with quickly and glade, but since I am not very familiar with python, and since now the rules of the contest changed and we can use whatever language we want. I just wanted to use QT or Java.

But I'm having the same problem as when I was trying to use quickly with Python and Glade... I didn't find a way to have the toolbar set as primary in order to appear with the Ambiance/Radiance theme from Ubuntu (which is a better looking one than the original)..

How can I solve this problem ?

Thanks in Advance,
Luis da Costa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of similar support in Qt. You could always manually color it to the same color.

Comment: Thank you for your answares. Yes but it will not look the same :S... If the user change the theme of Ubuntu the software will not fallow :S...